# .htaccess - how to avoid a subdomain to be seen on google or similar?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file for your consideration:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
#+FollowSymLinks must be enabled for any rules to work, this is a security #requirement of the rewrite engine. Normally it's enabled in the root and we #shouldn't have to add it, but it doesn't hurt to do so.

RewriteEngine on
#Apache scans all incoming URL requests, checks for matches in our #.htaccess file 
#and rewrites those matching URLs to whatever we specify.

#allow blank referrers.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?dev.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# request is for http://dev.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.site.com$ [NC]

# user-agent is a search engine bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|yahoo|msnbot) [NC]

# return forbidden
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

**I wish not to make dev.site.com public via google search or similar.**

I've place this. Should I wait ? Or is there something else that I should do ?

Comment: What's wrong with robots.txt?

Comment: @MichaelHampton are you suggesting that I should use a specific robots.txt for dev.site.com that tells crawlers to not see nothing ? And another robots.txt for site.com ? If I use a robots.txt that enables site.com, wouldn't we enable dev.nuvemk.com as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess isn't really the place to block websites from showing up in Google search indexes.  [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) is one of the methods designed for this purpose.

Placing this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

In a file named "robots.txt" in your root directory of dev.site.com should stop it from appearing.

Alternatively you could include a [meta tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710) in the pages you don't want to appear, such as:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Or if it's *only* Google that you want to not index your page, but allow others robots you can use:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

The downside to this in a development/production type scenario is you'll have to do something to make sure those tags don't appear in your production code (assuming you *do* want Google to index you production server).